# Android-Service killed with "no longer want" - how to restart it?

Tags: android, service

We have a Service that continuously collects sensor data on the phone. This service should run "forever", e.g. as long as the user wants, and not be killed by the system.

For clarification, this service is **not** intended for an app to be released in the market to the general public, it is written for a scientific study. So the people running the app are fully aware that their battery will sucked empty faster than usual, this is no problem.

Anyways, my problem is that the service gets killed after a while of running. Sometimes after an hour, sometimes only after like 7 oder 10 hours.

The Log-Entries when the service gets killed look like this. It just says "*no longer want*", sometimes without even calling onDestroy(), as far as I can tell.

```
07-20 17:07:11.593 I/ActivityManager(   85): No longer want my.project.datalogging (pid 23918): hidden #16
07-20 17:07:11.593 I/WindowManager(   85): WIN DEATH: Window{44c61570 my.project.datalogging/my.project.datalogging.DataLoggingApp paused=false}
07-20 17:07:11.603 I/BackgroundService(23925): onDestroy()
```

Or later (after I manually restarted it):

```
07-20 19:00:49.677 I/ActivityManager(   85): No longer want my.project.datalogging:BackgroundService (pid 24421): hidden #17
07-20 19:00:49.677 I/ActivityManager(   85): No longer want my.project.datalogging (pid 24415): hidden #18
07-20 19:00:49.807    85 10707 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{44f1ea58 my.project.datalogging/my.project.datalogging.DataLoggingApp paused=false}
```

I often see other services being killed with "*no longer want*" and then immediately restarted with "*Scheduling restart of crashed service*". For example here with runkeeper:

```
07-20 17:30:45.503 I/ActivityManager(   85): No longer want com.fitnesskeeper.runkeeper (pid 24090): hidden #16
07-20 17:30:45.603 W/ActivityManager(   85): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.fitnesskeeper.runkeeper/.services.RunKeeperService in 5000ms
07-20 17:33:52.989 I/ActivityManager(   85): Start proc com.fitnesskeeper.runkeeper for service com.fitnesskeeper.runkeeper/.services.RunKeeperService: pid=24292 uid=10099 gids={3003, 1015}
```

The logs show no record of low memory. Testing is done on (several) Nexus One with 2.2 (Froyo FRF91).

Is there any way I can achieve this behaviour with my app? Automatic restarting after being killed?

Or this this something totally different that just looks similar in logcat?

If you need any more information, just ask and I'll try to provide it :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How do you start the service? Have you tried [`startForeground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))? That's not an absolute guarantee, of course, but should at least lengthen the lifespan.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We don't use startForeground(), but it seems like a good idea. I implemented it and I'm currently testing to see if it hels. This can take a while, since the service was already able to survive several hours without getting killed.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a standard Android way of guaranteeing the service stays up, while working in the Java space (a separate watchdog service, scheduled to run periodically and check on your service still being up?). If not, you may need to go down into the NDK and Linux layer...

Comment: Thanks for the startForeground() idea, the service has now been running for almost 24 hours on two separate phones and wasn't killed. Seems to do the trick :-)

Comment: I overcame this problem by setting an alarm to start the service after ten minutes from boot. Works fine as of now!

Answer (score 6):

Try overriding the onCreate() method of your service. If the service is killed and then restarted it's onCreate() is called, but not onStart(). So you can, for example, add call to onStart() from onCreate to make it behave like the RunKeeperService.

Comment: Vote up. Totally agree that the solution should be to invoke a start method within onCreate. I disagree about calling onStart - it should not be invoked directly. Just invoke you own method to generally start the service.

Comment: Just a side note, I was having this same issue. It seems onStart does get automatically called. logcat shows "Scheduling restart of crashed service..." and after 5 secs, my service restarts. Same behavior in froyo and ICS/JB.

Comment: Adding to the above, if your onStartCommand returns START_STICKY, then Android will call onCreate and onStartCommand.

Comment: Agreed with previous comments.  It calls me onStartCommand with a null intent, and that null intent is a useful clue because that is the only time I get a null intent in onSTartCommand.

Comment: START_STICKY is basically the same as the previous behavior, where the service is left "started" and will later be restarted by the system. The only difference from previous versions of the platform is that it if it gets restarted because its process is killed, onStartCommand() will be called on the next instance of the service with a null Intent instead of not being called at all. Services that use this mode should always check for this case and deal with it appropriately.