# ActivityManager No longer want my app

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm developping an Android application that need to run on an Android device for like 12 hours in a row. 
The device does nothing except using this app, so it is always in the foreground.
After a variable delay my app got killed by the OS with this message:

```
I/ActivityManager(  360): No longer want com.my.app (pid 1234): empty for 10292s
I/qtaguid (  360): Failed write_ctrl(s 0 10066) res=-1 errno=1
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(  360): setKernelCountSet(10066, 0) failed with errno -1
I/WindowState(  360): WIN DEATH: Window{415f9718 u0 SurfaceView}
I/WindowState(  360): WIN DEATH: Window{415b8f08 u0 com.my.app/com.my.app.MainActivity}
W/WindowManager(  360): Force-removing child win Window{415cc938 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{415b8f08 u0 com.my.app/com.my.app.MainActivity}
```

My app is displaying a local html file with a VideoView and use a service to keep a real time connection with a server.
I think it could be related to the service but i couldn't find a clue for that.
Is there a way to get a stack of what is going on for this kind of errors ?

**EDIT:**

I tried to run my app without any service and the problem still happen so it is not related to the service.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is my code for launching the service.

**Activity**

```
     private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,IBinder binder) {

            Log.d("ServiceConnection", "Service connected");

            SocketClientBinder rmBinder = (SocketClientBinder) binder;
            socketService = rmBinder.getService();
            isBound = true;

        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            isBound = false;
        }
    };

    public void onDestroy() {
            //we unbind our service to avoid keeping the connection
            if (isBound) {
                unbindService(mConnection);
                isBound = false;
            }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            if( ! isBound) {
                //We bind our activity with our service
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SocketClientService.class);
                bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE | Context.BIND_WAIVE_PRIORITY | Context.BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY | Context.BIND_IMPORTANT);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3297235/1893766) with your service

Comment: This solution recommend using startForeground but i start my service with a bind which must retain my service while my activity is active. Furthermore i just completely disable my service to test without it and the problem still happens, so it is not service related...

Answer (score 1):

> Empty process
>
> A process that doesn't hold any active application components. The
>   only reason to keep this kind of process alive is for caching
>   purposes, to improve startup time the next time a component needs to
>   run in it. The system often kills these processes in order to balance
>   overall system resources between process caches and the underlying
>   kernel caches.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: I have read some solution who relate this problem to an empty process but my activity is always in the foreground so my process should be considered as active right ? I don't understand why my process could be considered has empty. If it is the case how to avoid that ? Thanks

Comment: Are you using delegates(callbacks)? If so, your Activity could be considered inactive after the onCreate()-method finishes.

Comment: What do you mean by delegates ? Is-it a handler ? If so no, basically its an activity with a webView and 2 VideoView which always stay in the foreground and which is bind to a service. The service spawn his own thread and is used for socket communication.

Comment: how does the service tell the app to draw something? (this is the time to paste some code in your question).

Comment: I added some details on the service but as i said in my edit the problem is not related to the service since the problem still occurred when i remove my service. The service didn't draw anything on the UI it is just here to collect some data in the background. Thanks for your help SatelliteSD