# android component that never gets destroyed by the system

Tags: android, service

I am developing android application right now, **which sends requests to the server every 4 seconds**. I need to make sure that app **will keep sending them even if it goes to background** (by pressing home button, opening another app or receiving phone call). As far as I know, the best solution for this is to use **services**. The question is, does service guarantee that it will never get destroyed by the operating system? And if it does get destroyed how can I handle this situation (restart the service)?

Or may be there is a better solution than android service?

App can have any permission over device or operating system, but it must not be rooted. So we can easily update it through google play store.

Thank you very much in advance!

PS. Please don't hesitate to ask me questions if something is unclear.

Comment: I feel like this will absolutely demolish battery life and data usage for most individuals.

Comment: every 4 seconds? what? don't do that... and for the other thing, you must check if android destroy the service for any reason and start it again.

Comment: App tracks user location coordinates and sends them to the server. Battery life time is not a concern, since access to this app is granted to only certain users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Service is indeed what you're looking for, however bear in mind the following things:

1) Services can and will eat up battery life if left unchecked. In your case specifically every one of those 4 second calls will cost you a little more battery life.

> I feel like this will absolutely demolish battery life and data usage for most individuals. –  CollinD

2) Services will NOT be destroyed by the android OS unless they fail/error out (which you can set conditions for in the service), or they are paused/destroyed by the application.

3) The last chance a user has to change/modify a service before their application closes is in the OnPause() or on Destroy() method.  After these are called the application is closed and the service cant be modified without reopening the app so make sure you call anything you need to to make sure the service persists in one of those methods.

I'm not sure if this completely answered your question so let me know if theres anything else I can clarify but it seems like you are using the proper android component for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for reply! In addition to your answer I found this, which was also very helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297204/android-service-killed-with-no-longer-want-how-to-restart-it?rq=1